# Hidden dropdown style button Bootstrap or make it disable

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to make a notification button. How can I disable this style or make it hidden from Bootstrap button?

[image]

Comment: You could add the `disabled` attribute to the button and then create a special class to override the border on the `dropdown-toggle::after` pseudo-element. That would disable the button and remove the carrot.

Comment: @RichDeBourke dosen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an example with three dropdown buttons on a navbar.

- The first button (from the left) is disabled and it has a special class `dropdown-no-carrot` — you could show this if there are no notifications.
- The second button is like your active dropdown button.
- And the third button uses the same `dropdown-no-carrot` class and instead shows a count, which is the way many sites let users know that there are messages.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .dropdown-no-carrot::after {
        border-color: transparent !important;
        content: none;
    }

    .dropdown-no-carrot .badge {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .rounded-button {
        border-radius: 5rem;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-light rounded-button dropdown-toggle dropdown-no-carrot mr-3" type="button" id="dropdownNotification1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" disabled title="No notifications">
            <i class="far fa-bell fa-lg"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownNotification1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-light rounded-button dropdown-toggle mr-3" type="button" id="dropdownNotification2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Click to see notifications">
            <i class="far fa-bell fa-lg"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownNotification2">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-light rounded-button dropdown-toggle mr-3 dropdown-no-carrot" type="button" id="dropdownNotification3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Click to see notifications">
            <i class="far fa-bell fa-lg"></i><span class="badge badge-danger">3</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownNotification3">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```